How to correctly detect user actions on Android?
I'm using Share.open from react-native-share on Expo react native app.
Share.open() always returns { success: false, dismissedAction: true } on Android, regardless of whether user shares or cancels. So, I cannot detect the user action correctly.
Tested on both Android device and emulator, all with the same result.
Do I need to add some configurations to make it work?
Is there a workaround or a fix to properly detect the user actions on Android?
Here is my code to open share sheet.
import Share from "react-native-share";

const onShare = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await Share.open({
      title: "Invite Friends",
      message: `Hi there, Hello! Please install this app:\n`,
      url: playStoreLink,
      failOnCancel: false,
    });

    console.log(res);

    if (res.success) {
      showAlert("Shared successfully", "success");
    } else if (res.dismissedAction) {
      showAlert("Dismissed sharing", "success");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert("Failed to share", "error");
  }
};


Packages.
{
    "expo": "~51.0.22",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-share": "^11.0.3"
}


There is no way to know via share library to detect which app user has clicked on dialog because platform doen not provide callback. The workaround is to get the sahrable apps via bridge and show your custom dialog.

You're right. I don't intend to know the exact action. I just hope to get success: true after user has clicked on any option without dismissing the share sheet.

I think it is possible in ios but not in android. I will revert back when I am near my system
